# Reduced Gröbner bases are minimal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, computer-science, groebner-basis, groebner-generators

Let $F$ be a free module (of finite rank) over $S = k[x_1, \dots , x_r]$ with monomial order >. Let $M \subset F$ be a submodule and let $B = \{g_1, \dots , g_t\}$ be a Gröbner basis for $M.$

I want to show that if $B$ is reduced, then $B$ is minimal.

I have  the following definitions.

1. $B$ is a minimal  Gröbner basis if $\operatorname{in}(g_1), \dots ,\operatorname{in}(g_t)$ is a minimal set of generators for $\operatorname{in}(M).$
2. $B$ is a reduced  Gröbner basis if, for each $i, 1 \leq i \leq t:$

$(i)$ $\operatorname{in}(g_i)$ is a monomial(i.e., the coefficient in $k$ is 1), and

$(ii)$ $\operatorname{in}(g_i)$ does not divide any term of $g_j$ for $i \neq j.$

Also, if I am given that:

If $\operatorname{in}(M)$ is generated by  $\operatorname{in}(g_1), \dots ,\operatorname{in}(g_s)$ for some $s \leq t,$ then $\{g_1, \dots , g_s\}$ is also a  Gröbner basis for $M.$

Also, if my previous knowledge is (From Eisenbud "Commutative algebra, with a view toward algebraic geometry" pg.328 and pg. 325)::

If $>$ is a monomial order, then for any $f \in F$ we define the initial term of $f,$ written $in_{>}(f)$ to be the greatest term of $f$ with respect to the order $>,$ and if $M$ is a submodule of $F$ we define $in_{>}(M)$ to be the monomial submodule generated by the elements $in_{>}(f)$ for all $f \in M.$

A Gröbner basis with respect to an order $>$ on a free module with basis $F$ is a set of elements $g_1, \dots , g_t \in F$ such that if $M$ is the submodule of $F$ generated by $g_1, \dots , g_t,$ then $in_{>}(g_1), \dots , in_{>}(g_t)$ generate $in_{>}(M).$

I am not sure how to show the minimality in our case? I am guessing that I should proceed by contradiction but still the idea is not fully figured in my mind. Can someone help me removing the confusion in my mind regarding this proof?

Comment: This is not a [good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) right now. Please improve your post with an [edit]. (Also, it strikes me as a poor choice to publish a question before you're done writing it - please consider waiting until you're finished in the future.)

Comment: [This](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~dmehrle/notes/old/alggeo/15BuchbergersAlgorithm.pdf) could help.

Comment: @MathLove You’re welcome! I’ll take a look at the questions but I’m not very knowledgeable on this topic, I just happened to have recently read that document.

Comment: Also, that link gives an alternative definition of minimal Gröbner basis from which it is easier to see the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, by the given, $B$ is a reduced  Gröbner basis if, for each $i, 1 \leq i \leq t:$

$(i)$ $\operatorname{in}(g_i)$ is a monomial(i.e., the coefficient in $k$ is 1), and

$(ii)$ $\operatorname{in}(g_i)$ does not divide any term of $g_j$ for $i \neq j.$

And since the given definition of $B$ being a minimal Grobner basis means that for each $i = 1, . . . , t$, we have the following:

1-$\operatorname{in}(g_i)$ is monomial(i.e., the coefficient in $k$ is 1).

2- $\operatorname{in}(g_i)$ does not divide $\operatorname{in}(g_j)$ for any $j$ different than $i$ because otherwise, the given set will not be a minimal set of generators for $\operatorname{in}(M),$

Then, $1$ is satisfied because $B$ is a reduced  Gröbner basis by assumption and hence $i$ is correct, $2$ is satisfied because $(ii)$ is correct and if $\operatorname{in}(g_i)$ does not divide any term of $g_j$ for $i \neq j,$ then sure it will not divide $\operatorname{in}(g_j)$ for any $j$ different than $i$ because if $>$ is a monomial order, then for any $g \in F$ we define the initial term of $g,$ written $in_{>}(g)$ to be the greatest term of $g$ with respect to the order $>.$

Comment: Do you require generators in the minimal generating set to have coefficients $1$? (I don't see this requirement in your question but it is a requirement in the textbooks). If so, the proof is ok to me.

Comment: I think they will not be minimal in that case because I should divide by the coefficient .... I am just following Eisenbud ..... maybe I misunderstood Eisenbud.

Comment: They are both fine. Having coefficient not $1$ doesn't affect the generating set too much.